# The line below throws "Runtime error 5": Invalid Procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

It would be great if someone suggests why it is throwing like error while adding ModelRelationship.Add in excel macro

```
'Add the relation
Public Sub AddRelation(ParentTableName As String, ParentColumnName As String, ChildTableName As String, ChildColumnName As String)

    Dim relations As ModelRelationships
    Set relations = ActiveWorkbook.model.ModelRelationships

    Dim tables As ModelTables
    Set tables = ActiveWorkbook.model.ModelTables

    Dim ptIndex As Integer
    ptIndex = TableIndex(ParentTableName, tables)

    Dim pfIndex As Integer
    pfIndex = ColumnIndex(ParentColumnName, tables(ptIndex))


    Dim ftIndex As Integer
    ftIndex = TableIndex(ChildTableName, tables)

    Dim ffIndex As Integer
    ffIndex = ColumnIndex(ChildColumnName, tables(ftIndex))

    **relations.Add _
        ForeignKeyColumn:= _
            tables(ftIndex).ModelTableColumns(ffIndex), _
        PrimaryKeyColumn:= _
            tables(ptIndex).ModelTableColumns(pfIndex)**

End Sub
```

Comment: I can only think that you're choosing the wrong tables/columns for `ForeignKeyColumn` and `PrimaryKeyColumn`: they must be in compliance for a one(primary) to many(foreign) relationship model